# Which is the best posture to Practice meditation?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation

Does any one know, which is the best posture to be assumed for practicing meditation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Bhikkhus, the bhikkhu following the practice of my Teaching, having gone to the forest, or to the foot of a tree or to an empty, solitary place, sits down cross-legged, keeping his body erect, and sets up mindfulness, orienting it.
>
> Then with entire mindfulness, he breathes in and with entire mindfulness he breathes out.
>
> [Maha-satipatthana Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.22.0.bpit.html)

The above is the standard posture for meditation (i.e.: sit down cross-legged). Even though I can't remain in this posture for a long time due to back pain, I personally believe this is the best posture for meditation. Having said that there are many other postures suitable, depend on your situation (walking, sitting, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a 'best posture' for meditation (although I have a yoga book which attributes all sorts of special mystical powers to the full lotus).

The best posture is the one that's best for you, that gives you a stable base (knees and buttocks) and lets you maintain your spine in a good upright position. For some that will be full lotus, others half or quarter, others burmese (all on a cushion), and for others it will be seiza on a cushion or bench.

You definitely shouldn't be deciding how to sit based on answers from people on the internet, you should go to a temple or monastery where experienced meditators with a variety of cushions and benches can observe you and help you find the posture that's best for you.

Answer (score 3):

Purists would say in full-lotus

Most reasonable would say that, half-lotus or cross legged

Sitting on a chair or bed is fine in all honesty.

Not falling asleep but being comfortable are the 2 major concerns.

Answer (score 2):

The best posture? Simple:

The posture that is most comfortable and affords the least distractions to your mind (aches, pains, etc).